# Matching multiple columns and assign codes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help with Excel in matching multiple columns (here 3 columns) and assign codes to the values if they are unique or present in duplicate or triplicate and also the column in which they are present. To be more clear, I am providing an example and also the codes, which are as below:

```
| A   | B   | C   | D   | E   | 
|   11|   22|   22|   11|     | 
|   22|   44|   11|   22|     | 
|   33|   77|   33|   33|     | 
|   44|   99|   88|   44|     | 
|   55|   33|   99|   55|     | 
|   66|     |     |   66|     | 
|     |     |     |   77|     |      
|     |     |     |   88|     | 
|     |     |     |   99|     |
```

the overall description of the data is that the columns A, B and C contain the data, whereas D column contains all the unique values of the columns A,B and C. I E column, I want the codes for the unique values based on their occurrence in the type of columns and also number of times occurred. The If conditions and codes are as below:

if value present in all three columns A, B and C then code "T" 
if value present in two columns A and B then code "U" 
if value present in two columns A and C then code "V" 
if value present in two columns B and C then code "W" 
if value present in only A, then code is "X" 
if value present in only B, then code is "Y" 
if value present in only C, then code is "Z"

So, the code should be in column E and the expected output should be as shown  below:

```
| A   | B   | C   | D   | E   | 
|   11|   22|   22|   11|    V| 
|   22|   44|   11|   22|    T| 
|   33|   77|   33|   33|    T| 
|   44|   99|   88|   44|    U| 
|   55|   33|   99|   55|    X| 
|   66|     |     |   66|    X| 
|     |     |     |   77|    Y|     
|     |     |     |   88|    Z| 
|     |     |     |   99|    W|
```

I tried using nested if with MATCH, AND and NOT conditions in Excel-2010, but nothing worked out. I have huge data to work out and hence cannot be done manually.

Please help me sort this problem.

Thanking you in advance.

Ashalatha

Comment: What does your latest try with the formula look like? This should be possible with MATCH, IF and AND formulas.

Comment: I could get the counts of their occurrence using the formula =COUNTIF($AC$2:$AI$74,AQ2) and also match with one column using the formula =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$D$1:$D$45,0)),"",A2), but was unable to do multiple matching among the columns and assign the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another long formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$10,0))=TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$10,0))=TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$C$1:$C$10,0))=TRUE,"T","U"),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$C$1:$C$10,0))=TRUE,"V","X")),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$10,0))=TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$C$1:$C$10,0))=TRUE,"W","Y"),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,$C$1:$C$10,0))=TRUE,"Z","")))
```

Drag/Copy down as required and change the range as per your data.

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: 425 characters less than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

A very long formula. I am sure there must be an easier way of doing this:

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)<>0)=TRUE,"T",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)=0)=TRUE,"U",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)<=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)<>0)=TRUE,"V",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)<>0)=TRUE,"W",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)=0)=TRUE,"X",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)<>0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)=0)=TRUE,"Y",IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0),0)=0,IFERROR(MATCH(D1,C:C,0),0)<>0)=TRUE,"Z","")))))))
```